# pass output to function

Tags: bash, function, input

I know I can pass arguments to a bash function like

```
function output () {
  echo 'text' > text.txt;
  echo $1 >> text.txt;
  echo 'more text' >> text.txt;
}
output something;
```

But I actually need to pass the output of another script or program and have it in one variable, so I am able to call the function like

```
output $(ls);
```

... and have the output of ls in one single variable in the function. Is that possible? How?

Or can I at least echo every single input to the function?

Comment: You'll find a lot of help with bash on the superuser.com stackexchange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try quoting the arguments:

```
output "$(ls)";
```

or changing your function to

```
function output () {
  echo 'text' > text.txt;
  echo "$@" >> text.txt;
  echo 'more text' >> text.txt;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash 
output=`ls -larht` 
/bin/echo -e "$output"
```

Comment: Doesn't work the way I meant. :/ I want to pass this output to the function into one variable.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible.

Consider this decimal to hex function, which takes the output of printf, and stores it in a var called NUM.

```
d2h()
{
  NUM=$(printf "%x\n" $1)
  echo $NUM
}
```

Comment: In bash, `printf` has this wonderful `-v` switch so that `a=$(printf ...)` is usually better written as `printf -v a ...` (think of C's `sprintf`). So that your `d2h` function would be more elegantly and more efficiently (think no subshells) written as `d2h() { printf -v NUM '%x\n' $1; echo $NUM; }`

Comment: that's legit. I'm impressed.

Comment: if you're not initializing a variable, it should be prepended with $.
Are you putting printf $total ?

Comment: I was initializing one - the `total` seemed to be the output of ls.